# iPhone app with restricted login

Tags: ios

I'm developing an app that parses the website of my college to pull exam grades. This requires a valid student id.

Will apple reject apps that are only usable by certain users e.g. students of a certain college? Any experience on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems, when submitting application, give apple review team some test credentials (you will see a field for that in submit form) so they can check your application, and you should be good to go...

We have an application that can be used by our employees only and it is in appstore for a long time, nobody never made any problems about it..

Comment: hello kviksilver, is your app still in the app store? we got the same case here for an future planed release.

Comment: Yup.. one of our latest apps was invitation only...  and it went trough same way as above.. just give credentials to apple, and they should not mind...